# How to generate a sitemap for my MediaWiki wiki family?

Tags: php, bash, mediawiki, sitemap, wiki

I am well aware of the existence of the maintenance script generateSitemap.php. I got a unique multi-language wiki setup though. That is i guess why it does not really work.

So after i do `php -f generateSitemap.php` i get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/var/www/mySite/_inc/../.ENVIRONMENT): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/mySite/_inc/settings.inc.php on line 12
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in /var/www/mySite/wiki/LocalSettings.php on line 174
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in <b>/var/www/mySite/wiki/LocalSettings.php</b> on line <b>174</b><br />
DB connection error: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:8889)
```

I got ONE single `LocalSettings.php` and only ONE database using prefixes. It changes depending on the user language like or what he/she selects so:

`de.mySite.org`
`en.mySite.org`
`es.mySite.org`

and so forth.

How can i run my maintenance script and get my sitemap? Any ideas are welcome.

**Edit:**

I tried setting different parameters [as shown here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:GenerateSitemap.php). I did not get it right yet.

**Edit2:**

I plan to use a Cron to update sitemap automatically via a bash command.

Comment: You need to post the code you use to handle your wiki family or this question is impossible to answer. What are your canonical URLs? How do you link the various language versions of each page? Do their titles vary depending on the language (e.g. Page/en, Page/es)? Does their content really differ? Is it an option to use something like `sed` to alter the sitemap locations after MediaWiki generates it?